# Uppercase links in a file in PHP

Tags: php, css, hyperlink, uppercase

Still on my way to learn PHP basics. ATM, I'm trying to find a way to "highlight" links description in a file.

let's say, if I got something like

```
 <body>Hello World <a href=http://web.com title="link">This is a link</a>
```

it would turn into

```
 <body>Hello World <a href=http://web.com title="LINK">THIS IS A LINK</a>
```

This far, I only managed to replace a single part by using this code

```
<?php

$matches = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
preg_match('/=".*a>/', $matches, $links);
print_r($links);
?>
```

Do you see any way to uppercase all these links, along with their titles ?

Comment: Surely css would be more appropriate here

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this in PHP. This is a design decision, so it should be done with CSS:

```
a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

If you really have to do it in PHP, you can use [preg_replace_callback()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), which allows you to write your own function that handles the replacement. This could look like this:

```
<?php
$string = '<body>Hello World <a href=http://web.com title="link">This is a link</a>';
$string = preg_replace_callback("/(<a.+title=[\"'])(.+?)([\"']>)([^<>]+?)(<\/a>)/", "callback_strtolower", $string);

echo $string;

function callback_strtolower($matches) {
    var_dump($matches);
    return $matches[1] . strtoupper($matches[2]) . $matches[3] . strtoupper($matches[4]) . $matches[5];
}
?>
```

Result:

```
<body>Hello World <a href=http://web.com title="LINK">THIS IS A LINK</a>
```

Note that this regular expression doesn't match all possibilities on how to write the html tags, you will have to adapt it.

Also note that it is usually a bad idea to use regular expressions to modify or parse HTML code. The recommended way is to use a DOM parser:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach ($links as $link) {
    foreach ($link->childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child instanceof DOMText)
            $link->replaceChild(new DOMText(strtoupper($child->wholeText)), $child);
    }
    if ($link->hasAttribute("title")) {
        $link->setAttribute("title", strtoupper($link->getAttribute("title")));
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: But what about the `title` text? They want that changed to upper as well.

Comment: I must do it in php, that's the tricky point... I thought of using preg_match or _preg_replace combined with strtoupper, but this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Text of anchor: css rule

```
a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

text for attribute TITLE (i wonder you'll set it with PHP somehow):

```
$myTitleInPhp = strtoupper($myTitleInPhp );
```